# Laravel validation on array with two fields exists on a database row

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a input array with each item contain 2 fields:

```
"items" :[
    {
        "product_id" : 23232,
        "product_offer_id" : 3434
    },
    {
        "product_id" : 4545,
        "product_offer_id" : 67676
    }

]
```

I want to verify if the `product_offer_id` and `product_id` exists in `products` table. Current rules:

```
$rules = [
    'items' => 'required',
    'items.*.product_id' => 'required|exists:products,id',
    'items.*.product_offer_id' => 'required|exists:product_offers,id',
    'items.*.quantity' => 'required|numeric',
];
```

Without array I did it like this:

```
$product_id = \Input::get('product_id');

$rules = [
    'product_id' => 'required|exists:products,id',
    'product_offer_id' => [
        'required',
        \Illuminate\Validation\Rule::exists('product_offers','id')
        ->where(function ($query) use ($product_id) {
            $query->where('product_id', $product_id);
        })
     ]
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to run your input array which contains your items against the rules that you have written using the Laravel class Validator.

`Validator::make($yourInputArray, $rules)->validate();`